# how to use model.fit in spatial pyramid pooling net with keras

Tags: keras, keras-2

SPP net is used for variable size input images. SPP Net implementation in keras in [here](https://github.com/yhenon/keras-spp/) uses two model.fit for two sizes of images. I have 278 images of all different sizes, so how to use model.fit in this case? and how keras calculating efficiency and other performance parameter after two model.fit uses? I am quoting some lines from spp [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729.pdf) where author write that

For   a   single   network   to   accept variable  input  sizes,  we  approximate  it  by  multiple networks  that  share  all  parameters,  while  each  of these networks is trained using a fixed input size. **In each  epoch  we  train  the  network  with  a  given  input size,  and  switch  to  another  input  size  for  the  next epoch**. Experiments show that this multi-size training converges  just  as  the  traditional  single-size  training,and leads to better testing accuracy.

Should we have to use as many epoch as we have no. of variable size images?

Comment: @Daniel Möller can you please see the issue.

Comment: Please someone provide answer

Comment: One way I could think of is to do clustering on the sizes of images into a chosen number of clusters and have the fixed kernels use the centroids.

Answer (score 0):

You can try generator (see [stanford.edu](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)).

---

If all images are different sizes, then the batch size should be 1. Pay attention to the X and y shapes.

```
class WordImageGeneratorSPP(object):
    def __init__(self, shuffle=True):
        self.shuffle = shuffle

    def generate(self, items):
        while 1:
            if self.shuffle:
                random.shuffle(items)
            for item in items:
                X = item[0]
                y = item[1]
                yield X, y

train_gen = WordImageGeneratorSPP().generate(train_data)
model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen, ...)
```

---

You can plot the generator output, but you should also pay attention to the X and y shapes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_gen = WordImageGeneratorSPP().generate(train_data)

for X, y in train_gen:
    plt.imshow(X)
    plt.title(y)
    plt.show()
```